# php help on getting id from query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

im quite new here and i want to ask for your help if possible.
I am passing info between two tables in one MYSQL database.

Here is my code:

```
$query1=mysql_query("select id, nazov, status from addd");

$querykategoria=mysql_query("SELECT id, kategoria, idfirma from properties where idfirma='$query2['id']'"); // =================>HERE IS THE PROBLEM
$query3=mysql_fetch_array($querykategoria);

echo "<table><tr><td><h3>Nazov</h3></td><td><h3>Kategoria</h3></td><td><h3>Status</h3></td><td></td><td></td>";

while($query2=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
{
echo "<tr><td><a href='firma/firma-properties.php?id=".$query2['id']."' class=nazov>".$query2['nazov']."</a></td>";
echo "<td>".$query3['kategoria']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$query2['status']."</td>";
echo "<td><a href='edit.php?id=".$query2['id']."'>Edituj</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=".$query2['id']."' class=zmazat>Zmazat</a></td><tr>";
}
```

And the problem is this code:

```
$querykategoria=mysql_query( "SELECT id, kategoria, idfirma from properties where idfirma='$query2['id']'" );
```

I know that this code will output me an error because i dont have variable $query2 defined yet. BUT how can i get this to somehow to work?

My question is how do i get that id from query2 and store it to a variable like $newid so i can pass it like here:

```
$querykategoria=mysql_query( "SELECT id, kategoria, idfirma from properties where idfirma='$newid'" );
```

?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to combine your first and second queries with a `JOIN` to get the results you want:

```
"select 
    t1.id, t1.nazov, t1.status, t2.id, 
    t2.kategoria, t2.idfirma 
    from addd t1 
    join properties t2 on t2.idfirma = t1.id");
```